# why mvc validation does not work in my code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have simple MVC code having a form with validation.but my validation for name property(required) does not work.I create BreakPoint in my controller after "InsertStudent" action result.

so I run that and fill the form without filling the name text box and I expect "IsValid" in my controller to be false.but it is true!!!

my view is:

```
 @model HelloWorld.Models.student

    @{
        Layout = null;
    }

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>AddStudent2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

        @using (Html.BeginForm("InsertStudent","home",FormMethod.Post)) {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            <fieldset>
                <legend>student</legend>

                <div class="editor-label">
                   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
                   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
               </div>
               <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Family)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Family)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Family)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Age)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Age)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Age)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
                </div>

                <p>
                       <input type="submit" value="Create" />
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        }

        <div>
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and this is my controller:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult index()
        {
            return View("home");
        }
        public ActionResult addstudent()
        {
            student stud = new student();
            return View(stud);
        }

        public ActionResult InsertStudent(student stud)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid==true)
           {
              //sahih
           }
            else{
               //ghalat
            }


            return View("addstudent");
        }

        public ActionResult AddStudent2()
        {

            student stud2 = new student();
            return View(stud2);
        }

    }
}
```

and model is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace HelloWorld.Models
{
    public class student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
         [Required]
        public string Family { get; set; }
         [Required]
        //[MaxLength(5)]
        public int Age { get; set; }


        public string Email { get; set; }

    }
}
```

please help me

Comment: Your "Name" property isn't required. Your "Family" property is. It's a typo?

Comment: yes that is right

Comment: You should update your example and your code to add the required attribute on the Name property. Let us know if the validation still doesn't fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have a `Required` attribute on your Name property. Add it and it the validation should fail

```
public class student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Family { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You do not need `AllowEmptyStrings = false` (the default is `false`)

Comment: Please do not waste tie answering off-topic questions which will be closed

Comment: wndrr yes it failed.you mean i could not have required  attribute on name property anyway?!!

Comment: Yes, you do need the `[Required]` attribute. If you do not add it, only the non-nullable types will be required (string is nullable so it's considered optional by default)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem.

I had to put the `[required]` attribute below my `name` property instead of putting it above.

```
public class student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
         [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings=false)]
        public string Family { get; set; }
      [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        //[MaxLength(5)]
        public int Age { get; set; }


        public string Email { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Keep in mind that metadata (information about a property/method or literally anything) will always come before the thing it describes :-)

Comment: note: As pointed out by @Stephen Muecke, `AllowEmptyStrings = false` is redundant because `false` is the default value.